# Failed to boot after upgrade 20.04 to 22.04 (Lenovo Ideapad 3)

Tags: boot, upgrade, 22.04, ahci

EDIT: I saw the cause. To make the touchpad works on 20.04 I introduced in the grub 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pci=nocrs quiet splash"' instead of 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"'. But then I can't make work the touchpad. I reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04 from zero and unless I introduce that instruction, I can boot 22.04 without...the touchpad.

ORIGINAL: I have a laptop where I did an upgrade to 22.04 from 20.04, but apparently it doesn't boot.

[image]

"Failed to start port 0"
"ALERT! UUID=2bbf1926-ac61-4bfa-bd7b-586f294d97a4 does not exist."

If I go to the prev kernel, 5.13 (ubuntu 20.04's kernel) boot without much problem, but Wayland works so awful (I have to change to Xorg).

Someone knows what I should do?

Laptop: Lenovo ideapad 3

CPU: Intel core i5 10th gen

Setting BIOS:

- SATA config: AHCI mode
- UEFI

Thanks!

Comment: I saw the cause. To make the touchpad works on 20.04 I introduced in the grub 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pci=nocrs quiet splash"' instead of 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"'. But then I can't make work the touchpad. I reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04 from zero and unless I introduce that instruction, I can boot 22.04 without...the touchpad.

Comment: touchpad? try modprobe i2c-hid and try i2c-hid-acpi. if it helps watch out for my other postings about this .... ;-)

Comment: Exactly the same problem on lenovo 15-IIL model after upgrading to 22.04 LTS. Seems like the boot drive is unable to mount.

Comment: I tried with modprobe i2c-hif and i2c-hid-acpi. No results. @opinion_no9

Comment: Seems the pci=nocrs doesn't allow to boot the OS. @Harry

Comment: Yep. Its a problem with kernel v5.15 in ubuntu. The drive isn't able to mount after appending pci=nocrs. It works in v5.13

Comment: Yeh, I saw it. But it works so awful with Wayland, isn't it? At least in my case. @Harry you tried with the last kernel? (5.17)

Comment: @Noctis Yes. With the ubuntu mainline kernel 5.17 its the same issue. I am guessing that it is going to take time to fix this thing up. Atleast 3 months or so. Till then I am staying on 20.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: This error was fixed in 5.18.xx.